# Aligning an overflow menu item's icon with the Toolbar Title

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-constraintlayout, android-optionsmenu

EDIT: I now have a custom `Toolbar` in a separate layout (`toolbar.xml`) from that of my `activity_main.xml`. The new layout now contains just one `TextView` for the title. The `Toolbar` however, has an `overflow menu` which contains only one item (the settings icon) and it's set to `showAsAction="always"`. However, in the layout preview i can't see the actual settings icon thus i'm not able to `align` my title `TextView` with the icon in order to avoid any misalignments (see image). Any ideas?

toolbar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:background="@drawable/toolbar_gradient"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/toolbar_title_placeholder"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_semibold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

As you can see in the image below, my title `TextView` is misaligned in regards to the `overflow menu item` (settings icon). Is there a way i can fix that?

[image: result]

Comment: Your toolbar height  is set to `70dp`. Toolbars are normally `56dp` or `?attr/actionBarSize`. This is why the settings icon is displaced toward the top. Change the toolber height so your title and the settings icon will have their vertical centers align.

Comment: @Cheticamp what if i need the toolbar's size to be `70dp` to achieve a certain look though? Can't anything be done in that case?

Comment: OK. So you want to move the text up a little so it centers vertically with the settings icon. Is that right?

Comment: Nope, actually i want the settings icon to move down a bit to align with the title so that they both are at the horizontal center of the toolbar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`70dp` is a non-standard height for a toolbar which is the underlying issue with your layout. If you stay with the `70dp` toolbar height, you will need to make adjustments to the toolbar layout.

Here is one way that just modifies the XML layout. The `7dp` padding in the toolbar will shift the icon down. Corresponding changes to the text view keep it aligned.

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:paddingTop="7dp"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/toolbar_title_placeholder"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

To understand what is happening, make the changes and run the app. In Android Studio, go to Tools->Layout Inspector and choose your device and the app. What you will see is a dump of the layout that you can examine.

This method works with what you have posted. It may have side effects with the placement of other views so be on the lookout.

An alternatative involves code to retrieve the view that corresponds to the settings icon. If I recall, it's not pretty.

btw, you don't see the settings icon in Android Studio because menu items are added at run time.

Answer (score 2):

Add [**`CoordinatorLayout`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout) & [**`AppBarLayout`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout) with **`app:elevation="0dp"`**.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
                app:elevation="0dp">

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                  android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                  android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                  app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                  app:titleTextAppearance="@style/Toolbar.TitleText"
                  app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                    > 
                 //Your work
                </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

            </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

     <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
       >

      //Your work
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for helping me with my issue. When i apply the above changes i get an error about `@style/App.Theme.AppBarOverlay` since i have no such style. Same for `"@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"`. What kind of style should that be? I tried replacing it with `android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"` which is what i found to be the answer in similar posts but that just turns the whole Toolbar to white. Also, should my bottomNavigationView be outside of the ConstraintLayout as well ? I also added my `styles.xml` in the post

Comment: @SteliosPapamichail you can add `<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />` in style section.

Comment: sadly it's still just white, i also added this (idk if it's correct) `<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" />`

Answer (score 0):

As we know Android has some specific rules in design pattern like toolbar size, icon size, etc.

Android prefers using actionBarSize in the toolbar.

```
?android:attr/actionBarSize
```

In your case, if you need your custom size toolbar then you should create your own custom toolbar like below:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:background="@color/colorWhite"
                android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
                android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                android:elevation="0.1dp"
                android:paddingEnd="10dp"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
                app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
                tools:targetApi="lollipop">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">


                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/search_layout"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="start"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">


                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/toolbar_start_image_view"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"

                            />


                    </LinearLayout>


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/bold"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Visit Tulsipur"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/notification_layout"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="end"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">


                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/toolbar_end_image_view"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                       android:src="@drawable/ic_notifications_none_black_24dp"

                            />


                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Now you can set on click in defined ImageView/Layout.

**OUTPUT**

[image]